# Configuration problems with TLS in Golang + C#

Tags: c#, go, rsa, tls1.2, x509certificate2

I am developing a video game and I am quite lost in the subject of secure communication between client and server. If anyone can give me a cable I would really appreciate it.

My project is based on a client (c # - Unity) + server (Go) that communicate through a TCP socket. Now I am adding security with TLS 1.2, and although following several articles and posts I have gotten a solution that apparently works, I think that I am not really getting a secure communication since although I change the client's digital certificate for a totally different one and unrelated to the keys everything still works the same, which makes me think that something I have not configured correctly

Regarding the use of RSA keys, I am using the following scheme:

- Server: Digital certificate generated with the private key (.pem) + private key to create the socket (.pem)

```
//// Server Go ////

cert, _ := tls.LoadX509KeyPair(PemCertPath, PrivateKeyPath)
config := tls.Config{MinVersion: tls.VersionTLS12, Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert}}
service := ServerAddress + ":" + strconv.Itoa(ServerPort)

socket, _ := tls.Listen("tcp", service, &config)
```

- Client: Digital certificate generated with the private key (.pem) to connect to the socket.

```
//// Client C# ////

byte[] certBytes = Convert.FromBase64String("AS9ggSEPw5yp7+IH5S9ingq+.........."); //Cert .pem
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certBytes);
X509CertificateCollection certCollection = new X509CertificateCollection(new X509Certificate[] { cert });

tcpClient = new TcpClient(serverAddress, serverPort);
sslStreamSerma = new SslStream(tcpClient.GetStream(), false, ValidateCertificate); 

sslStreamSerma.AuthenticateAsClient(sermaName, certCollection, SslProtocols.Tls12, false);
```

I am quite confused with this ... I do not understand what is happening here so that regardless of the digital certificate that the client uses, the communication continues to work ... Should I create 2 pairs of keys, one for the client and one for the server? Should the certificate be generated with the public key?

If anyone can help me I would really appreciate it ...

Comment: That's how TLS works. Why do you expect it to work differently?

Comment: @Adrian What I don't understand is because it doesn't matter what certificate I use from the client. Even if you use one that is not generated from the server keys ...

Comment: Right. The client and server keys have no relation to one another.

Comment: @Adrian In that case, the digital certificate that I load in X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2 (certBytes) is not a certificate from the server keys but a client certificate? So how is the client capable of encrypting the information so that only the server can decrypt it if it does not have its public key?

Comment: That's how TLS handshaking works. TLS is what underpins things like HTTPS; every browser doesn't hold the public key of every web server in the world. If you had to have the public key in order to establish a connection, TLS would be impossible. You can read a thorough breakdown of TLS handshaking here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_handshake

Comment: @Adrian Ahh I understand! So I think the origin of my problem is that I would need to work with 2 pairs of keys, private and public from the server + private and public from the client ... is it possible?

Comment: Why do you even want to use client certificates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your client certificate doesn't have associated private key which is required to perform client authentication.

```
byte[] certBytes = Convert.FromBase64String("AS9ggSEPw5yp7+IH5S9ingq+.........."); //Cert .pem
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certBytes);
```

this code part reads only public part of the certificate, not private key.

Comment: Ok, in that case I should upload a certificate in .pfx format where the private key is also included, right?
Something like:
X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2 (pfxCertPath, certPwd);

But would we be talking about a certificate generated with the private key of the server or with that of the client?

Comment: @unRabano: Unless you configure your server to *request* client certificates they won't even be used, making all the effort you're putting in to configure them wasted. SSL/TLS is common, SSL/TLS with client certificates is rare.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I thought that for a TLS communication it was necessary to authenticate the client as well. But I have seen that this is somewhat optional ... Is dispensing with client authentication still safe?

In that case, shouldn't I use any certificate in the client code?

Comment: I don't know, do you need to authenticate your clients? Client authentication may be needed depending on your system, but typically it's achieved using a username and password. This is the simplest, most common, and best understood method of authenticating the client. This authentication is performed under the protection of TLS. Don't get me wrong, certificate-based TLS client authentication is an option, but it has it's own set of challenges that often make it a poor choice. Of all the websites you use that require authentication, how many use passwords? All of them probably.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Ok, now I think I am beginning to understand how it works correctly, yes, I am doing the authentication under username and password. The only thing I am trying to achieve is a secure communication at the encryption level ... I would only need to know what configuration I need on the client to connect to the server correctly, that is, I need to have the server's certificate within the client code to connect or not do i need anything?

Comment: Most systems are preconfigured with a set of trusted CA certificates, including the standard .Net distros. As long as your server has a certificate signed by one of these CAs (e.g. letsencrypt) your client should be able to securely connect to the server with TLS without requiring any significant configuration on the client side. You don't need to load any certificates.